# How to uninstall ubuntu-desktop in Bash on Windows

Tags: command-line, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I ran the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to see if the UI would work within Bash for Windows (which was just released in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update).  Now that I know it doesn't work, I want to uninstall everything it installed (a little over 1,000 packages).  Is there an easy way to do that?  Or is there a way to for me to just start over cleanly with Bash for Windows?

Comment: Did you try this? Although slow for most people worked just fine. https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/637

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop Unity does work. Xubuntu Desktop works better though (ie faster). However in both cases you need to install `VcXsrv` or a similar X-Windowing system for Windows first. There will be limitations with some GUI packages such as GIMP I believe but overall it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely remove your Ubuntu instance, you can run the LXRun command from cmd/PowerShell (as per the [docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuuif.png)):

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
```

If you then want to re-install your Ubuntu instance, just run the following from cmd/PowerShell:

```
lxrun /install
```

### Update 2018-02-06

Update since a lot has changed since I wrote this answer ;)

The guidance above remains w.r.t. the original Ubuntu distro that WSL downloaded and installed when you first ran WSL in Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

In Creators Update and later, you enable WSL, and then install your distro of choice from the Windows Store. To remove a store-delivered distro, just right-click it's tile in the start menu and hit "Uninstall":
[image: Uninstall Ubuntu]